# Can git corrupt code without having the corrupted code coming from a commit?

Tags: javascript, git

I'll try explaining, i was merging a branch to another no problems, i run the code then get a tons of code error like this

'consti' not a keyword (exemple not real message)

git replaced the line

```
const a = which_one_is_broken.find(i => i.id === 0)
```

by the line

```
consti= which_one_is_broken.find((i) => i.id === 0)
```

but the second line does not come from anywhere, i don't have it in the source branch ?

What did happened ? can someone help me try figure it out ?

i've checked both commit parents none of them have the faulty line

In another instance the damage was such as :

```
source[(index += 1)] = textureProvider
```

became

```
source[(index += 1)] = dtureProvider
```

That merge did corrupt 27 files, i rolled it back and im good now but what the heck happened ? how can i prevent this for happening again ?

Comment: I've seen git inserting a line to a wrong place in complex merges, but never corrupting just a part of a line.

Comment: Seems like a bad merge where either somebody did something by hand and broke it then or perhaps a different tool tried to automatically process the conflicting files. Without knowing exactly how the merge was done, it's very hard to say why did it break.

Comment: I've seen failures of this sort when there are hardware problems, such as bad RAM. Typically line lengths don't change though—you wouldn't get `dtureProvider` for instance—and instead you get a bit-flip in one or several characters, e.g., `i` becomes `j` for instance. Bugs can of course come from anywhere, hardware or software, but after this kind of glitch I'd be tempted to run diagnostics, if available.

Comment: Hi @Sylvain, and welcome to SO. Your particular issue happened after a merge, and you did not provide many details on how that merge was performed - did you run `git merge other/branch` on your local PC, or was is a PR ? do you know if some conflicts occured, and if they were fixed by someone else ? that sort of details. If relevant : you may run hardware checks as @torek suggested, on the system(s) involved in the merging. If you need more assistance on your issue, please give us more information on how this merge was performed. Happy hacking !

Comment: One extra technical step to see if it could be a hardware failure : check the bytes of the modified lines (e.g : read the bytes in `cat file | hd`), to see if some extra non printable characters are present around `consti` or `dtureProvider`

Comment: The merge was done using the Pull request from github website, i was the only one working with the code at that time, im currently the only dev in my company so im certain it wasnt bad code from someone, i would have noticed, code would not compile at all with all those glitches, hardware issue yes but it was running on github's server, how could that happen on such large scale website ? i've corrected everything by hand now

Comment: Luckyly we had a backup git server were i did not push the corrupted code on, so i was able to re construct everything but my bosses now ask how can we prevent that from happenning again and i can't answer them properly as im not sure what happened in the first place